Does Stack Exchange keep the original images of the uploaded images?
Does Stack Exchange keep the original images of the uploaded images or at least keep some information that aren't publicly exposed such as metadata, file names or >2MiB images?

Regarding Exactly what metadata is preserved when uploading an image on the network?, that question doesn't mention the original files (e.g., for files above 2 MiB) and file names. Also the answer may have changed since SE changed the image hosting solution.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution at the very least there remains the question about +2 MiB files and filenames.

If yes, then they've quite a bit of suitable material to train AI image-filters to attenuate the regular porn outbreaks.

Just curious (and frankly, not very familiar with this topic), but why explicitly ask about >2MiB images? Are images below this size-limit handled differently (I assume inmemory vs temp file during upload)? Or is there a standard, that explicitly distinguishes between the two cases?

@Lino >2MiB images get recompressed. I'm eating downvotes on https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/405311/178179 as we speak because of that
